# Access NodeJs Express server from Android Phone

Tags: android, node.js, express, server

I have a website that runs with Node.js and express on the localhost with the port 3000, and I want to access to this localhost with my Android Phone.
I've tried a few things but none of them worked for me.

Here's the index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/pages/index.html'))
});

app.get('/about',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/pages/about.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to requests on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your phone and laptop or desktop must be on the same network. You can share your phone's hotspot to the laptop.
Then run the `ipconfig /all` command (on windows to check your network address). You should see `IPv4 Address. . .  : YOUR IP(Preferred)` somewhere close to the end.
That is the address you will type on your android browser.

Then you will modify your index.js file's listen function to

```
...
app.listen(port, "YOUR IP ADDRESS" || "localhost" ,() => {
  console.log(`Listening to requests on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

After saving that, open `YOUR IP ADDRESS:PORT` in your phone browser. e.g `192.53.13.8:3000` and voila.

Comment: That doesn't work on my phone, don't know why

Comment: So I had to open the port on my router, but it works

Comment: Great. The solution I gave earlier just makes it work on either your phone or laptop. To make it work on both, use app.listen( port , [" YOUR IP ADDRESS", "localhost" ],()=>{ ... })